# --ros-args argument is always present in launched Node

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to launch a node that requires common command line arguments.
In my launch file, I added a Node() instance in my LaunchDescription which contains the `package`, `executable` and `arguments` attributes. However the launched program complains about not knowing about argument `--ros-args`.
I thought it was the `ros_arguments` attribute in the Node that added the `--ros-args` argument to the launch command so I don't understand why I am getting this error.

I am running Ubuntu 22.04 and ROS2 Humble.

How can we launch a program from a launch file without the launch file adding the `--ros-args` argument to the launch command ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/412486/--ros-args-argument-is-always-present-in-launched-node/) by [Sam_Prt](https://answers.ros.org/users/108956/sam_prt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2023-02-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [christophebedard](https://answers.ros.org/users/29634/christophebedard/) on 2023-02-14**:
Can you share your launch file and the code that reads command line arguments?

**Comment by [christophebedard](https://answers.ros.org/users/29634/christophebedard/) on 2023-02-14**:
Also, can you clarify what exactly is complaining about the `--ros-args`? Is it your own code, or is ROS 2 itself complaining about it?

**Comment by [christophebedard](https://answers.ros.org/users/29634/christophebedard/) on 2023-02-14**:
In short, `--ros-args` is always added to the commandline arguments, but at the end after any `arguments`: https://github.com/ros2/launch_ros/blob/6daacbce4bade7ed40f86f16a30a08b4d7ee9272/launch_ros/launch_ros/actions/node.py#L209. If you write code to read these commandline arguments, you might need to filter it out.

**Comment by [Sam_Prt](https://answers.ros.org/users/108956/sam_prt/) on 2023-02-20**:
Oh ok, I thought it was more of an either/or logic. Thanks for your help ! Would you like to post an answer so I can accept it ?

**Comment by [christophebedard](https://answers.ros.org/users/29634/christophebedard/) on 2023-02-20**:
sure, done!

**Comment by [christophebedard](https://answers.ros.org/users/29634/christophebedard/) on 2023-02-21**:
Note that I edited my answer to mention `rclcpp::init_and_remove_ros_arguments()`. It just popped into my head.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`--ros-args` is always added to the commandline arguments, but at the end, after any arguments: https://github.com/ros2/launch_ros/blob/6daacbce4bade7ed40f86f16a30a08b4d7ee9272/launch_ros/launch_ros/actions/node.py#L209. If you write code to read these commandline arguments, you might need to filter it out.

You can also ask `rclcpp` to remove ROS arguments from the arguments vector (`argv`) when initializing. Then I imagine you wouldn't need to filter it out. See `rclcpp::init_and_remove_ros_arguments()`: https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/blob/28e4b1bd738c23e3ede2c70bf35786ce829ae910/rclcpp/include/rclcpp/utilities.hpp#L140

---

Originally posted by [christophebedard](https://answers.ros.org/users/29634/christophebedard/) with karma: 641 on 2023-02-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1